Insert Tag in WordPress Post
I have below code.
$args = array(
    'post_title'   => $this->h1,
    'post_content' => $this->profile_text,
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'post_type'    => 'post',
    'meta_input'   => $this->to_meta_array(),
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
    $this->id = $post_id;
    $success  = true;
}

$united_states_term = term_exists('United States', 'category');
if (!$united_states_term) {
    $united_states_term = wp_insert_term('United States', 'category');
}

$united_states_term_id = $united_states_term['term_id'] ?? null;


if ($united_states_term_id) {
    wp_set_post_categories($this->id, [$united_states_term_id], true);
}


$uncategorized_term_id = get_option('default_category'); 

$current_categories = wp_get_post_categories($this->id);


if (($key = array_search($uncategorized_term_id, $current_categories)) !== false) {
    unset($current_categories[$key]);
}


wp_set_post_categories($this->id, $current_categories);

// added tags.
if ( 0 !== $this->id ) {
    // get country category.
    $country_term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'country', 'category' );

    if ( $country_term ) {
        $country_term_id = $country_term->term_id;
    } else {
        $country_term    = wp_insert_term( 'Country', 'category', array( 'slug' => 'country' ) );
        $country_term_id = $country_term['term_id'];
    }

    $tags       = array();
    $categories = array();

    
    foreach ( $this->tags as $tag ) {
        // insert new term.
        if ( $tag['is_country'] ) {
            // check exists tag.
            $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $tag['slug'], 'category' );

            // add country category.
            $categories[] = $country_term_id;

            if ( $term ) {
                $categories[] = $term->term_id;
                continue;
            }

            $new_term = wp_insert_term(
                $tag['name'],
                'category',
                array(
                    'slug'   => $tag['slug'],
                    'parent' => $country_term_id,
                )
            );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $new_term ) ) {
                $categories[] = $new_term['term_id'];
            }
        } else {
            // check exists tag.
            $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $tag['slug'], 'post_tag' );

            if ( $term ) {
                $tags[] = $tag['slug'];
                continue;
            }

            $new_term = wp_insert_term( $tag['name'], 'post_tag', array( 'slug' => $tag['slug'] ) );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $new_term ) ) {
                $tags[] = $tag['slug'];
            }
        }
        
    }

    // unique value in array.
    $tags       = array_unique( $tags );
    $categories = array_unique( $categories );

    if ( ! empty( $tags ) ) {
        wp_set_post_tags( $this->id, $tags, false );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        wp_set_post_categories( $this->id, $categories, false );
    }
}

This code is inserting Post Tags 2 times.
How can I insert Tag only once ?

If you are using wp_set_post_tags this you can pass either
array of exiting tags id or array of string.
If it is a string then it will create a new one and assign that, if you are passing an id then it will assign that term_id of post_tag.
As per your code I can see you are passing tag's slug and this is being treated as a string and that is why it is creating the tag again.
